# Page keeps refreshing when its crucial for the data to be shown on the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So i got this thing to wrok but it seems that it shows what i need (u need to accept the regulations for example) but after that the page immediately refreshes, tho i need the data to just stay on the page. How to deal with it? 
This too much code restriction is really annoying so i have to write something like this in here to avoid it - deleting the unnecessary stuff will take too much time so i hope i wont get banned or sth lol.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Usługi informatyczne </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styl.css">
        <body>

    <div id="kontener"> 
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>

            <div id="menu">
                <a href="index.html">O nas</a>
                <a href="uslugi.html">Usługi</a>
                <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
            </div>

          <div id="baner">
            <img src="animacjak.gif" alt="">
        </div>

            <div id="blok_glowny">
                <hr />
                    <h2>Kontakt</h2>

                <form id="formularz"  action="">
                    <table>
<tr>
    <td>Imię:</td>  <td><input type="text" id="imie"><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Nazwisko:</td>  <td><input type="text" id="nazwisko"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>E-mail:</td>    <td><input type="text" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Usługa</td> <td><textarea name="usluga" id="usluga"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>   <td><input type="checkbox" id="regulamin" value="regulamin">Zapoznałam/em się z regulaminem</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>   <td><input type="reset" value="Resetuj"><input type="button" onclick="przeslij()" value="Prześlij"></td>
</tr>
</table>
                </form>
                <div id="pokaz">  </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            function przeslij(){
                var imie=document.getElementById("imie").value;
                var nazwisko=document.getElementById("nazwisko").value;
                var usluga=document.getElementById("usluga").value;
                var regulamin=document.getElementById("regulamin").checked;
                document.getElementById("formularz").submit();
if(regulamin==true){
document.getElementById("pokaz").innerHTML=imie.toUpperCase()+" "+nazwisko.toUpperCase()+"<br />"+
"Treść twojej sprawy:"+usluga+"<br />"+"Na  podany adres e-mail zostanie wysłana oferta";
}
else{
document.getElementById("pokaz").innerHTML="Musisz zapoznać się z regulaminem";
document.getElementById("pokaz").style.color="red";
                        }
            }

</script>

                <hr />
            </div>

            <div id="stopka">
                <p>Autor strony: 00301011337</p>
            </div>
    </div>       

        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you see in your console...

Comment: How do you know the form is not submitted?

Comment: unexpected identifier in line 61, form shows nothing, if i for exaple not check regulation box it should say "u cant left it unchecked ets" in red, at the bottom of the site

Comment: Now, after the edit, back to the question: How do you know the form is not submitted?

Comment: it says "przeslij is not defined" in console and "unexpected identifier in line 61" like i said before.

Comment: As you can see, the example code doesn't give that error. Please add the real code you have.

Comment: i pasted the original but stackoverflow said its too much code so i deleted the table in which the form was and some divs that were not necessary

Comment: The line `... = imie.toUpperCase() + " "` lacks `+` at the end of the line, but that shouldn't cause an error (it just ignores the rest of the string when inserting it to `innerHTML`. If you've fixed the function declaration (which causes Unexpected token { error in Chrome), make sure the page is really refreshed and the new code is executed instead of some cached code. When ever you've fixed the token error you're getting, also the przeslij is not defined error goes away. But, but ... you'll be in front of new challenges with this code, move the very first line to the end of the function.

Comment: console shows no erros but it still shows nothing

Comment: Yep, because the form is submitted, and a new page is loaded as the server response. If you want to keep the page, you've to post the form using AJAX.

Comment: this has to be done without ajax, pure js

Comment: AJAX is just a term, a name for a techinque called also XHR. You don't need jQuery to send a XHR.

Comment: hey i got it, help me with the refreshing please, i also updated the code

Answer (score 1):

Your function is missing the parentheses

```
function przeslij() { ... }
```

And to make the reset button works, just change its type to "reset"

```
<input type="reset" value="Resetuj">
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
kontakt.html:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: przeslij is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick  (file:///C:/Users/rafal/Desktop/Nowy%20folder%20(4)/kontakt.html:45:111)       i still got these errors, what do they mean? how it is that my function is not defined?